# Prove the solution of these differential equations are circular orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, circles

Prove that if
$$\ddot y + \omega^2 \dot x = 0$$
$$\ddot x - \omega^2 \dot y = 0$$
then
$$x^2 + y^2 = R$$ where R is a constant.

Comment: This looks fun!  What have you tried so far?  Do you have a question?

Comment: I integrated both sides of both the equations but cant seem to find anything

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui check the differential equations, they should be $\ddot x + \omega^2x = 0$ and $\ddot y + \omega^2y = 0$ for cicular orbits.

Comment: @gimusi these are the actual equations: $a_x = \dfrac{eb}{mc}v_y$ and $a_y = -\dfrac{eb}{mc}v_x$ where $a$ and $v$ are acceleration and velocity

Comment: Note that $a_x=\dot v_x$ and $a_y=\dot v_y$ so that the coupled system is of order 1. The position still follow circles, but with arbitrary center, $(x-c_x)^2+(y-c_y)^2=R^2$.

Comment: How did you arrive at that equation? Is it a known phenomenon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same as solving $y^{(4)}+ω^4y=0$. As the roots of the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^4+ω^4=0$ are $λ=\fracω{\sqrt2}(\pm 1\pm i)$, each basis solution $e^{λt}$ resp. 
$$
\exp(\pm\tfracω{\sqrt2}t)\cos(\tfracω{\sqrt2}t),\;
\exp(\pm\tfracω{\sqrt2}t)\sin(\tfracω{\sqrt2}t),
$$
also has an exponentially growing or falling factor, there are no circles as solution.

Comment: These equations are for a motion of a particle in a uniform magnetic field and that $a_x = \dfrac{eb}{mc}v_y$ and $a_y = -\dfrac{eb}{mc}v_x$ and the solution to these equations have to be a circular orbit with the center anywhere on the x-y plane

Comment: in other words we are finding the solutions to newton-lorentz equations

Comment: Ah, the force is orthogonal to the **velocity** vector. But then your equations should be $\ddot x = ω\dot y$ and $\ddot y =-ω\dot x$.

Comment: those are the equations but i just assumed $\omega^2$ to be the constant instead of $\omega$. Would it make a difference?

Comment: Note that the equations in your question connect acceleration and position, while the Lorentz equations connect acceleration and velocity.

Comment: Ohhhh yesss ill edit that. So how do we solve those equations?

Answer (score 2):

Let $z = \dot{x}+i\dot{y}$. Then $\dot{z} = \ddot{x}+i\ddot{y}$. Combining the two given equations, we get
$$\ddot{x} + i \ddot{y} - \omega^2 \dot{y}+i\omega^2 \dot{x}=0$$
$$\dot{z} + i\omega^2 z=0$$
$$z = Ae^{-i \omega^2 t}$$
for some complex constant $A$. You can write $A = c + di$ and expand into real and imaginary parts to give $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$, then integrate both to give the desired solution. Note that the paths of $x$ and $y$ won't necessarily lie on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = R$, but you will have $(x-a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = R^2$ instead.